# how to add a instance of a foreign key to an instance of a model that it points to

Tags: python, mysql, django, foreign-keys, models

I have a Django app wherein a user can schedule command line 'Jobs' to run on remote systems.  Here's my models.py defining Job and a foreign key relationship

```
class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 250, null = False, blank = False)
    user = models.CharField(max_length = 30, null = False, blank = False)
    command = models.CharField(max_length = 1000, null = False, blank = False)
    whenToRun = models.DateTimeField('Run Date', null = False, blank = False)
    output = models.CharField(max_length = 100000, null = True, blank = True)

class Host(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = False, blank = False)
    hasRun = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

Next I have a block of code that has some POST data indicating some hosts to add to a Job (hosts represent individual host names that the user wants to be running the command specified in the Job instance that the Host instance is connected to).

```
hostNames = list()
for p in request.POST:
    if "Host" in p: #Host is put in the input name attribute in the template as a sentinel
        hostNames.append(request.POST[p])
selected = getCheckedJobs() #a list of the jobs to add this host to
```

Now that I have the names assembled and jobs to add them to, I realize that I have no idea how to take a Job instance and add a Host instance that's associated with it.  Can anyone tell me how to go about this?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: On a side note, your `null = False, blank = False` is redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you have the right relationship structure?  With the foreign key on Host, each job can have many hosts but each host can only have one job.  Your comment says "a list of jobs to add this host to" - that's not possible with this relationship.

If it is right - you need to get your Host instance, then assign its `job` attribute to be the Job instance and save the Host instance.  Something like:

```
# assume selected_job is the job instance
try:
    host = Host.objects.get(name=hostname)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    # do something here to handle an unmatched hostname
    pass
host.job = selected_job
host.save()
```

Comment: Thank you, I may very well switch the relationship later.

Comment: The relationship should be obvious from what behavior you need to support.  Unlike a many-to-many relationship, it's not arbitrary which model has a foreign key field - that determines the direction of the many-to-one relationship.

Comment: Is it possible to instead of having a hierarchical relationship (where one Model contains a bunch of copies of the other model) that I have one instance for each unique Host and each unique Job and have all the relevant references between instead of having a bunch of copies of either Jobs or of Hosts?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that.  There aren't multiple copies of a given Job or Host instance.  The questions that should dictate your relationship structure are: 1) Can a host have multiple jobs at the same time?  2) Can a job have multiple hosts at the same time?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean.  Kind of if both models defined a ForeignKey although i'm sure that's not how you implement that.

Comment: If the answer to both questions is yes, then you should be using a ManyToMany field.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help Peter